# How to write an Jasmine test for the angular service using http get?

Tags: angularjs, http, jasmine

I already read a couple of posts, but still can't figure out the solution for me. I have an Angular service

```
App.factory('PoolService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    return {
        fetchAllPools: 
            function() {
                return $http.get('http://localhost:5555/demo/pools/').then( ...
```

And an Angular controller, that uses the service

```
App.controller('PoolController', ['$scope', 'PoolService', function($scope, PoolService) {
          var self = this;
          self.pool={id:null,name:'', description:''};
          self.pools=[]; ...
```

Now I'm trying to write a Jasmine unit test for the controller, that looks like:

```
describe('pool', function () {
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var $controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    describe('pool list', function () {

        it('after fetching pools the pool list should contain elements', function () {
            var $scope = {};
            var controller = $controller('PoolController', { $scope: $scope});

            controller.fetchAllPools();

            expect($scope.pools).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
});
```

The implementation of fetchAllPools()

```
fetchAllPools: 
    function() {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:5555/demo/pools/').then(
                function(response){
                    return response.data;
                }, 
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while fetching pools');
                    return $q.reject(errResponse);
                }
            );
        },
```

My problem is that service doesn't execute the http.get request - it is just waiting endless.

Can anyone please help? What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: is it angular or angular js

Comment: Can you share the implementation of `controller.fetchAllPools()`?

Comment: it is angular js. Here is the implementation of fetchAllPools:   fetchAllPools:

Comment: fetchAllPools: 
   function() {
    return $http.get('http://localhost:5555/demo/pools/').then(
      function(response){
       return response.data;
      }, 
      function(errResponse){
       console.error('Error while fetching pools');
       return $q.reject(errResponse);
      }
     );
    },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mock the service inside the controller test:

```
it('after fetching pools the pool list should contain elements', inject(function(PoolService, $q, $rootScope) {
  var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  spyOn(PoolService, 'fetchAllPools').and.returnValue($q.when([]));
  var controller = $controller('PoolController', { $scope: $scope });

  controller.fetchAllPools();
  $scope.$apply();

  expect($scope.pools).toBeDefined();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the http request is now executed! My test still fails: Chrome 58.0.3029 (Mac OS X 10.11.6) pool pool list after fetching pools the pool list should contain elements FAILED
 Expected undefined to be defined.
     at Object.<anonymous> (/...pool.test.js:31:27)
     at Object.e [as invoke] (lib/angular.min.js:38:477)
     at Object.workFn (lib/angular-mocks.js:2420:20)

Comment: It can't possibly be executed, since the whole point of the above code is to **mock** the service, i.e. replace its actual implementation by a fake one returning an empty array. Even if you called the real service, the $httpBeckend service itself is mocked by angular in unit tests: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpBackend

Comment: I understand! Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a way to test the http service with Jasmine?

Comment: I already gave you a link that exlains how to test code using $http.